# how to set blur screen to full page and at click page go to TOP

Tags: html, css

CSS1 worked:

```
.parentDisable
{    
        z-index:2000;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display:none;
        position:absolute;

        left:0;
        background: url(/images/btrans.png) repeat;
        color: #aaa;
}
#popup
{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: #6699ff;
    top:40%;
    left: 40%;
}
```

CSS2 Not worked:

```
    display:none;
    z-index:2000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

HTML

```
<div id="pop1" class="parentDisable">
            <center>
                <div id="popup">
                    <div id="loading"> </div>
                    <div id="popupText" align="left"> </div>
                    <a href="#" onClick="return hidePopup_('pop1')" >
                        <img style="position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0" alt="close" src="/images/close.png" width="40px" height="40px"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </center>
</div>
```

with CSS1 i got this but not full **HEIGHT** and i want this at current scroll position not at TOP not at BOTTOm
when i click on link my page goes to top and display as in image.
[image]
**UPDATE1** :
Remaining is `not to scroll page up|Top`
when i click on link page scroll-up to TOP.
Script :

```
// set full page height
    var hei = document.body.offsetHeight;
    $('#pop1').css({height: hei +'px'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `position: absolute` use `position: fixed`.

To prevent the page from jumping to top you need to include a `return false` within your javascript-function `hidePopup_`.

The link trys to jump to the anchor `#` and since there isn't one, it jumps to the top.

Comment: no the screen still goes up to TOP. but if i move scroll, The `popup` stay in middle of screen.

Comment: oh yes `#` takes the page to top.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a position:static for .parentDisable.  This will generally give you better results for what I think you're looking for.

Comment: static and relative takes whole page down to blur screen