# Wordwrap text inside a table column

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I got a table, one of the columns contains a lot of content.

I am trying to restrict the size of the table to 550px, trying to set the url column to 200px and making the url wordwrap - but it's not playing.

Bashing my desk with my head.
Here is snippet.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Foo</title>
    <style>
        .data-table td.topic {
            word-wrap: break-word;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 14px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .data-table {
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 550px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="data-table">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>URL</th>
                <th class="center-text" style="width:80px;">Status Code</th>
                <th class="center-text" style="width:95px;">Time</th>
                <th class="center-text" style="width:75px;">Link In</th>
                <th class="center-text" style="width:75px;">Links Out</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr class="">
                <td class="topic">
                    <a href="http://2.bp.xxxxxxxxxx.com/_n55gYT_sn0o/TGUybwgn6mI/AAAAAAAAAMQ/q4iOiN8yE4Y/s1600/xxxxxxxxxxxx+nutrition.jpg" title="http://2.bp.xxxxxxxx.com/_n55gYT_sn0o/TGUybwgn6mI/AAAAAAAAAMQ/q4iOiN8yE4Y/s1600/xxxxxxxxxx+nutrition.jpg" target="_blank"><b>http://2.bp.xxxxxxx.com/_n55gYT_sn0o/TGUybwgn6mI/AAAAAAAAAMQ/q4iOiN8yE4Y/s1600/xxxxxxxxxx+nutrition.jpg</b></a>
                </td>
                <td class="center-text">200</td>
                <td class="center-text">1.01</td>
                <td class="center-text"><a class="link_report" href="/link/report/to/91809/26">1</a></td>
                <td><a class="link_report" rel="urls_for_91809" href="/link/report/from/91809/26">0</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" id="urls_for_91809" style="padding:0px; border-bottom:0px"></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this code [pasted as above](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/v6x7Q/) is breaking the long link fine for me, what's the problem?

Comment: It seems to work for me - word-wrap: break-word is a CSS3 property, are you using a CSS3 compatible browser to test?

Comment: It seems to be fine in FF 3.6, Safari5 and Chrome 10 dont seem to like it. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to show the entire URL?

If not, you could use some jQuery to shorten it.

```
var links = $("td.topic a").get();
var bigLinks = [];
var smallLinks = [];

$("td.topic a").each(function(){ 
   bigLinks.push($(this).text())  
});

for(var i=0; i<bigLinks.length; i++){
  smallLinks[i] = bigLinks[i].slice(0,27);
  $(links[i]).text(smallLinks[i] + "...");  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G2PsZ/1/

Fyi... the slice is arbitrary.  You set the character count depending on how big you make the `table cell`.

All this does is replace the text in the `a` tag, making it shorter.  The link remains unchanged.

Comment: can u help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098224/how-to-set-blur-screen-to-full-page-and-at-click-page-go-to-top