# div and span together

Tags: html, css

I'm using a CSS style sheet to style several blocks in my HTML. The class *"header"* is used to denote these blocks.

In my CSS sheet I have:

```
.header
{
    background-color: #efefef;
    margin-bottom:.4em;
}
```

then in the HTML I have:

```
<div class = "header">
    <span style = "float:left;" >
    <b>My&nbsp;Colors</b></span>
    <span style = "float:right;" >
    <input type="text" name="color" value = "Enter&nbsp;a&nbsp;color"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" /></span>
</div>
```

along with several other blocks using `class = "header"`. The other blocks are being styled correctly, but the one above is not (the CSS has no effect on it).

Is there something going wrong with putting span tags inside a div? What would be the reason for the CSS working with the other blocks, but not this one?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are getting?

Comment: Also, according to the spec you can only float block-level elements (like `div`), not inline elements (like `span`), although floating a `span` usually works just fine in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the floats

like this

```
<div class = "header">
    <span style = "float:left;" > <b>My&nbsp;Colors</b></span>
    <span style = "float:right;" >
        <input type="text" name="color" value = "Enter&nbsp;a&nbsp;color"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </span>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

I added `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` right before `</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're floating the SPAN elements you'll need to tell your DIV to handle the flow properly. Adding `overflow:auto` to the class will do the trick.

Obligatory fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bznCp/1/

Comment: i think u have nice Css Knowledge can u help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098224/how-to-set-blur-screen-to-full-page-and-at-click-page-go-to-top

Comment: @raviparekh I only dabble in it :) Sorry, I checked out your question but I don't know the answer to your problem.